# How to configure uniqueness and custom validations with Judge Gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, client-side-validation

I am using the judge gem for client side validations on my rails app. Validations for my *User* model look something like this:

```
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /^[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+$/i 
  VALID_USERNAME_REGEX = /^[A-Za-z\d_]+$/

  validates :username,        :presence => true,
                              :uniqueness => true,
                              :length => { :within => 2..49 },
                              :format => { :with => VALID_USERNAME_REGEX, :multiline => true },
                              :exclusion => { :in => RESERVED_HANDLERS }, :on => :create

  validates :email,           presence: true,
                              length: { maximum: 50 },
                              format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX, :multiline => true },
                              uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
```

Since we're hitting the server for uniqueness I have exposed the :username and :email for judge in the initializers as well:

```
Judge.configure do
  expose User, :username, :email
end
```

Now here is the problem: Ideally I'd want email and username formatting to be validated on client side itself, without hitting the server, and yet I want to keep the same safeguards on the server side too. So notice the regex I have put in is compatible with rails & javascript both, and I've set :multiline => true for ^$ end characters also.

This is not working as expected however. Client side validation isn't working perfectly for 1. :uniqueness and 2. email/username format. Why would :uniqueness => true not work properly?

Answer (score 0):

For the regex problem:

Put this code in the judge.rb initializer:

```
Judge::Validator.class_eval do
  def to_hash
    {
      :kind => kind,
      :options => get_js_compatible_options(options),
      :messages => messages.to_hash
    }
  end

  private

  def get_js_compatible_options(options)
    method_name = "get_js_compatible_#{self.kind}"
    if self.respond_to? method_name, options
      options = self.send method_name, options
    end
    options
  end

  def get_js_compatible_format(options)
    format_options = Hash.new
    options.each do |key, option|
      format_options[key] = (key == :with) ? convert_regex_to_js_compatible(option) : option
    end
    format_options
  end

  def convert_regex_to_js_compatible(regex)
    js_regex_source = regex.source.sub(/^\\A/, '^').sub(/\\z$/i, '$')
    /#{js_regex_source}/
  end
end
```

Then use this regex:

```
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
VALID_USERNAME_REGEX = /\A[A-Za-z\d_]+\z/
```

Judge will automatically convert them to javascript compatible versions.